# cannot respond to warning in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

***I am getting a warning:***

> RS232Msg cannot respond to
>   "-initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded"

***Code is***

```
-(void)createMessage
{
     RS232Msg* pMsg;
     //pMsg = new RS232MsgRawEncoded(static_cast<int>nMessageNumber); in cpp
     pMsg = [pMsg initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded:(int)nMessageNumber];
}
```

`initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded` is a derived class of `RS232Msg`.
and `pMsg` is a pointer to `RS232Msg`. The createMessage is a method that is declared in RS232Msg ***How to make it to access ?***

Answer (score 0):

If you defined `initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded` in a class derived from `RS232Msg` you cannot use that selector with `RS232Msg*`.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you would like to add one more possibility of creating `RS232Msg` objects by initializing them with raw encoding.

You can do that in different ways. One is creating a sort of "factory" class (it would not be an orthodox factory as per GoF patterns, but that does not matter). This class can have a static function that is exactly your `initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded`.

Another option you have is define a category for `RS232` and then add the `initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded` into it. Categories are a way to extend classes without the need of subclassing them. This is a skeleton of how you would go about it in your case:

```
@interface RS232 (MyRS232Extension)
    (id)initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded:....;
 @end

@implementationRS232 (MyRS232Extension)

    ....

@end
```